# Destructuring a vector of maps

Tags: clojure

I have a function that queries my database for the X most recent entries, and it returns a vector of maps along the lines of:

```
[{:itemID "item1"
 :category "stuff"
 :price 5}
{:itemID "item2"
 :category "stuff"
 :price 54}
{:itemID "item3"
 :category "stuff"
 :price 435}
{:itemID "item4"
 :category "otherstuff"
 :price 32}]
```

How I go about destructuring a vector of maps(or is there a better method?) so that I can bind each value into a symbol along lines of:

```
item-1-id
item-1-category
item-1-cost
item-2-id
item-2-category
item-2-price
...etc
```

Having trouble grokking this, I get how to destructure a vector, or maps individually, but not a vector of maps, appreciate any help or insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simply impossible, since destructuring creates local bindings whose names must be known statically.

That's unless the total number of maps is known ahead of time, in which case you could of course write

```
(let [[{item-1-id :itemID ...} {item-2-id :itemID} ...] ...] ...)
```

The pattern could be captured in a macro, but the result would likely not be very pretty. (For example, introducing implicit bindings is not very pretty.)

A better solution might be to collect the various values in separate vectors:

```
(let [vector-of-maps (get-the-vector-of-maps)
      ids            (mapv :itemID vector-of-maps)   ;; note the mapv
      categories     (mapv :category vector-of-maps)
      ...]
  ...)
```

Then you can say `(ids 0)` to refer to the ID from the first map, `(categories 2)` to refer to the category from the third map etc.

This works because vectors in Clojure act as functions of indices, returning the associated values (for example, `([:foo :bar] 0)` returns `:foo`).

Or you could simply use `vector-of-maps` directly with `get-in`:

```
;; get ID from first map
(get-in vector-of-maps [0 :itemID])
```

See also `assoc-in` and `update-in` for producing modified versions of nested data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown, that gives me a pretty good idea of what's going on. One question though, playing with your example solution, I get clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentVector, any idea?

Comment: Apparently you're calling a vector with no arguments. Vectors can only be called as unary functions (with a single index argument).

Comment: Thanks, I (sorta) figured it out,taking vector-of-maps into its own def and then binding all the symbols via mapv works perfectly. That was an amazing help, thanks :)